# Connecting to Windows Remote File System with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to connect and count the number of files in a remote windows based server with Ruby.

```
   ruby-1.8.7-p352 :001 > Dir.entries("\\server_name\d$\directory_path").count
```

i also tried this

```
   ruby-1.8.7-p352 :002 > file_path = "\\server_name\d$\directory_path".gsub("\\", "/")
   ruby-1.8.7-p352 :003 > Dir.entries(file_path).count
```

The above lines appear to be insufficient.. as they return

```
    No such file or directory - \\server_name\d$\directory_path (Errno::ENOENT)
```

respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to show what your path is?

```
file_path = "\\server_name\d$\directory_path".gsub("\\", "/")
puts file_path #-> /server_named$directory_path
```

You have to mask the \

```
file_path = "\\\\server_name\\d$\\directory_path"
puts file_path #\\server_name\d$\directory_path
```

or

```
file_path = "\\\\server_name/d$/directory_path"
puts file_path #\\server_name/d$/directory_path
```

I think you must start the path with \. Normal slashes // will not work (I'm not sure about this, just try the other version if I'm wrong)

Comment: Thanks for that but it did not work.. i guess i should have stated that i had already tried those options..